# Why does Lubuntu show up this error? Is it a kernel panic?

Tags: kernel

This is the error.
My HDD on my old laptop reported 1000 bad sectors on the HDD.
This is the error that I got:
[image]

How do I fix this error in the future?
Thanks Jonathan Steadman. :)

Comment: I'm guessing its from your hard drive, in general I/O error showing there was a hardware problem.

Comment: @Liso thanks for your comment. I did have issues with the fan and the OS kept on getting corrupted by showing the Busybox error all the time even a new install show the error.

Comment: That's your sign, better replace it, hopefully you got a backup.

Comment: @liso it's ok it was only used for non-important data as I have a newer pc for college and home use. Besides, it was 32 bit now it's pretty useless I guess.

Comment: You can try hook up the disk to your other PC, and launch SMART test to see the verdict. My guess it will show failed sign.

Comment: I/O errors on drives is not good.  You can try reseating the drive, but doubtful that will help.  Looks like you have a bad drive.  As long as it is readable you can try to backup your data before replacing it.

Comment: @terrance thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: Please note:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is EOL (https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/) as it's a *flavor* and *flavors* never extended support from 3 years to 5 (only main Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server & Ubuntu Cloud did)  Your system also reports it's well behind (year+) on security fixes & patches (otherwise it'd say 18.04.5; refer https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ for date of ISO release, but installed systems upgraded before that date), so I hope your system is off-line.  Disk errors are not kernel related - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Lubuntu's manual page (LTS) for checking health is https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/3/3.1/3.1.7/kde_partitionmanager.html however it doesn't cover your release as all supported releases use LXQt.  Easiest fix is replace the *failing* drive as already stated

Comment: I think this answer: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19617/43926 shows that this question is on topic on Ask Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer.